# Cannot get .debug() messages to show up for slf4j in Java

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I can't get this to work. I've also tried the `--debug` option in IntelliJ. It's always printing "debug is not enabled" and never printing my .debug() messages to console. Any ideas?

**the .java file**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyClass {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public void myMethod() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.info("debug is enabled");
        }
        else {
            logger.info("debug is not enabled");
        }
        logger.debug("\n\ntest debug message\n\n");
    }
```

**src/main/resources/log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.logger.com.mycompany=debug
```

I tried updating my application.yml to set the logging level but it had no effect:

**application.yml**

```
  logging:
    level:
      root: DEBUG
      org.springframework.web: DEBUG
      guru.springframework.controllers: DEBUG
      org.hibernate: DEBUG
```

Comment: and you use `log4j` as the implementation of `slf4j`?

Comment: That's a good question. I see `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api` and `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j` in the External Libraries / Grade dependencies for the project. But I'm not certain. It's a Spring Boot project. I think maybe it uses logback by default?

Comment: there is no "default". `slf4j` is just a facade, you need an implementation, which seems to be `log4j-to-slf4j`. The advice, in general, is to use `logback` for your code and configure that.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. For example, Spring starters use Logback by default. The .info() lines are working. I'm simply unsure how to configure the logging level to debug (regardless of what implementation is under the slf4j facade). Well, thanks anyway for trying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. After poking around SO more, I updated my config file to set the logging level as follows:

**/src/main/resources/application.yml**

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: DEBUG
```

(note: indent level matters! It would only work when it was at the very top level of the .yml file, i.e. no indents)